# How do I pass npm parameters to dotnet publish?

Tags: npm, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, npm-install

Long story short, private npm registry, corporate network, can't download from github.

I need to pass

```
--no-optional
```

to the

```
npm install
```

that

```
dotnet publish
```

executes as part of

```
Target "PublishRunWebpack: (TargetId:162)"
```

Any ideas?  MSDN documentation @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21 is super unhelpful.

Using dotnet core 2.1, if it matters :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I swear, StackOverflow's greatest power is that the odds of figuring out your problem increase exponentially as soon as you ask the question.

The

```
PublishWebPack
```

is part of the csproj.  Unload / edit / modify to your heart's content!

Comment: This is what i've been using within VS 2017 when I publish and it works, but if you use the dotnet cli to do a publish, it seems like its ignoring the build configuration when using a Condition parameter with the command node